Current Measurement of a Brushless DC motor
I am trying to measure the current drawn by a brushless DC motor under load. This is to check if the propeller and the motor are a correct fit at the desired conditions (a range of rpm, say 0-8000rpm). I have attached an image of the current setup that I am using to perform current measurements using a Radioshack multimeter.
The motor speed is controlled via a Servo Exciter. However, the motor stalls as soon as it crosses 9-10A. As per the datasheet, the maximum continuous power of the motor at this setting is 200W, with a max. current of 20A.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything with the setup that I need to change?
Please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks.


is the ESC shutting down?

The issue you're experiencing with your brushless DC (BLDC) motor stalling at currents above 9-10A, despite its datasheet indicating it should handle up to 20A, could be due to several factors related to your setup

What’s the input voltage under load right at the ESC before it stalls?

@jsotola The ESC doesn't shut down, it just drops the motor rpm. The motor then keeps operating at that lower rpm and cannot be increased anymore, which leads me to believe that it is doing so by-design for safety. But why does the safety limits kicks in when it is supposedly operating within the allowable range of Amps.

@winny The input voltage is 11.1VDC.

@Ahmed read the ESC user manual

What’s the UVLO limit?

Is it why you are using a multimeter in the "power supply" of your setup (burn-out voltage)?
